# I have been trying to do text classification using transformer, but I am facing some issues when I am using the saved model for prediction

Tags: nlp, prediction, huggingface-transformers, text-classification

So, now when I add return_tensors="pt", I get labels, but they give incorrect prediction, which I think comes from the fact that when I trained I didn't use it. But if I don't use it I get error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size' for this command:

`data["predicted_label"] = data["tokenized_inputs"].apply(predict_label)`

So I am not sure why is `return_tensors="pt"` required when I didn't add it while training. And my prediction was giving good results when I was using `trainer.predict()` to check my test results. I am not sure how should I do prediction on new data?

````
     hg_train_data=Dataset.from_pandas(train_data)

    `tokenizer=AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")`

    def tokenize_data(data):
      return tokenizer(data['text'], max_length=128, padding='max_length', truncation=True)

    dataset_train=hg_train_data.map(tokenize_data)

# This is how I have tokenized my dataset.

    model=AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', num_labels=2)
trainer=Trainer(
model=model,
args=training_args,
train_dataset=dataset_train,
eval_dataset=dataset_test,
compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
callbacks=[EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=1)]
)
    trainer.train()
    trainer.save_model("./model")

# here I have trained my model and then saved it

# Then, I have loaded tokenizer and model

    loaded_model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("./model")
    loaded_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("./tokenizer")

# Tokenize and predict

    def predict_label(inputs):
    with torch.no_grad():
    logits = loaded_model(**inputs).logits
    predicted_label = torch.argmax(logits, dim=1).item()
    return predicted_label

# Tokenize the data using the tokenizer

    data['tokenized_inputs'] = data['text'].apply(lambda x: loaded_tokenizer(x, max_length=128, padding='max_length', truncation=True ))

# Apply the prediction function to each tokenized input

    data["predicted_label"] = data["tokenized_inputs"].apply(predict_label)

# Tokenize the data using the tokenizer

    data['tokenized_inputs'] = data['text'].apply(lambda x: loaded_tokenizer(x, max_length=128, padding='max_length', truncation=True, return_tensors="pt" ))```
````

Comment: You have to use `return_tensors="pt"` because you are inputting the data into a pytorch model. What are your `training_args`?